Image Sequence render issue
Im using an image sequence as a texture on a plane
The issue is when I render my scene it is not rendering the image sequence correctly.
My image sequence is simply some text that as the frames go on it says "Police in your body"
like so

Now here is my render result. It stops at "Police". Its like Blender is experiencing an issue with reading the image sequence properly. Its the same in the viewport its correct up until a certain point.

I  would greatly appreciate any help

When it's a texture on a plane, the very least you could do is show us a screenshot of the material setup of the plane. And you are sure the image sequence is correct, all frames are okay and in the place where Blender is looking for them?
